# Pascal - Shape Drawing

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops, pascal

So the task is to draw this shape :

```
******
**  **
*    *
**  **
******
```

The number of rows is set by the user,and it is labeled as n.In this case it is n=3.
So i tried splitting it in two , and i managed to get an output looking like this.

```
***
**
*
**
***
***
 **
  *
 **
***
```

My code :

```
translation : brojredova is number of rows
brojzvezda is number of stars *
broj praznih is number of empty fields
--------------------------------------------
```

```
program veasdsa; 
var 
  n,brojredova,brojzvezda,brojpraznih : integer;

begin
  readln(n);

  // prva polovina 1st half

  for brojredova := 1 to n do
  begin  
    // *
    for brojzvezda := 1 to ((n-brojredova) + 1) do
    begin
      write('*');
    end;

    writeln;
  end;       

  for brojredova := 2 to n do
  begin
    for brojzvezda := 1 to brojredova do
    begin
      write('*');
    end;

    writeln;
  end;   // ovde pocinje druga polovina ( second half starts from here)

  for brojredova := 1 to n do
  begin
    //prazna
    for brojpraznih := 1 to (brojredova - 1) do
    begin
      write(' ');
    end;

    // * 
    for brojzvezda := 1 to ((n - brojredova) + 1) do
    begin
      write('*');
    end;

    writeln;
  end;

  for brojredova := 2 to n do
  begin
    //prazna
    for brojpraznih := 1 to (n - brojredova) do
    begin
      write(' ');
    end;

    // * 
    for brojzvezda := 1 to brojredova do
    begin
      write('*');
    end; 
        
    writeln;
  end;
end.
```

I can't figure out how to get them together..
There is probably an easier way,but i tried doing it like this.

Comment: It is because you are trying to draw the two sides _separately_. You have to rethink a little. You need to draw both sides _one line at a time_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify by writing a very basic procedure which prints a character repeatedly.

```
procedure print_char_times (ch : char; n : integer);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
    write (ch)
end;
```

Now you don't need to repeat this loop over and over. With this defined, you just need to count `i` from 0 to `n - 1` to get the top half of the shape:

- Print `'*'` `n - i` times.
- Print `' '` `i * 2` times.
- Print `'*'` `n - i` times.

It's very straightforward to translate this to code.

```
program Test;
var
  i, n : integer;

  procedure print_char_times (ch : char; n : integer);
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    for i := 1 to n do
      write (ch)
  end;

begin
  n := 3;

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    print_char_times('x', n - i);
    print_char_times(' ', i * 2);
    print_char_times('x', n - i);
    writeln
  end;

  for i := n - 2 downto 0 do
  begin
    print_char_times('x', n - i);
    print_char_times(' ', i * 2);
    print_char_times('x', n - i);
    writeln
  end
end.
```